# rest api (client side) is working fine on local server but not on online server

Tags: php, web-services, api, rest, consuming

The following code works fine on local server but on online server throws `HTTP ERROR 500`. cURL is also enable. Have checked the error log it say;

> AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception
>   'Pph\ApiClientException' with message 'Unknown error HTTP/1.1 400 BAD
>   REQUEST\r\nSe

```
$tcom = $ApiClient->apiCall('get', 'companies');
echo "<table>"; 
foreach($tcom as $key=>$value){

  foreach($value as $k => $v){
    echo'<tr>';
    echo '<td>'  . $k . '</td>';
    echo '<td>'  . $v . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
  }
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: can you check value of `$tcom` on your server url ? use `print_r($tcom);exit;`

Comment: Also just ensure about database credentials too.

Comment: Why it only works on local server? What has to be done here?

Comment: Have you changed DB credentials for live server ? Your local db username/password will not work over live server.

Comment: @Rishi Thanx for the quick response. Yes credentials are allgood and i tried checking the value of $tcom on online server using print_r and the page was blank. But on local server value came: Array ( [1251] => Array ( [idstate] => 153 [ico] => 0 [name] =>.....

Comment: how you sure about db connection is good? if query is same and not output ? If all good, you should check url/path.

Comment: @Rishi ya i turned on the error reporting and it says: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Pph\ApiClientException' with message 'Unknown error HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST Server: nginx Date: Sat, 23 Jul 2016 12:15:36 GMT Content-Type: application/vnd+company.category+human Transfer-Encoding:

Comment: I must say check file url's

Comment: @Rishi i double checked the file url with a simple html code and it displayed fine.

Comment: @Rishi error log:  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Pph\\ApiClientException' with message 'Unknown error HTTP/1.1 400 BAD REQUEST\r\nServer: nginx\r\nDate: Sat, 23 Jul 2016 12:02:54 GMT\r\nContent-Type: application/vnd+company.category+human\r\nTransfer-Encoding: chunked\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\n\r\nArray\n(\n    [error] => No data format defined. Please provide one (human, phpserialize, json) as URL parameter like this: &format=phpserialize\n)\n'

Comment: error quote, code indenting

Comment: Error 500 is usually a synonym for "an error occurred on the back-end". So check the server's PHP log to see what error is was, and let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to provide one (human, phpserialize, json) as URL parameter like this: &format=phpserialize\n)\n'

Example: 
        $tcom = $ApiClient->apiCall('get', 'companies&format=phpserialize');